# How to normalize URLs in Hybris

Tags: spring, url, sap-commerce-cloud

When I search categories and products in User Interface, my URL looks broken like

```
�,  // c//p/010
```

how can I get rid of this characters?
Is there any out of box solution in Hybris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hybris does a lot of escaping special characters in category and product and content page URLs. Consider de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.url.impl.AbstractUrlResolver and all subclasses for that purpose.

Here are the most common ones:

- DefaultCategoryModelUrlResolver
- DefaultProductModelUrlResolver
- DefaultContentPageUrlResolver

Use them like this:

```
...
@Resource(name = "productModelUrlResolver")
private UrlResolver<ProductModel> productModelUrlResolver;
...
ProductModel product = productService.getProductForCode("myProduct");
String url = productModelUrlResolver.resolve(product);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you please kindly give me an example of code on DefaultProductModelUrlResolverr to be able to get rid of that characters

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `core-spring.xml`

```
<alias name="mysiteProductModelUrlResolver" alias="productModelUrlResolver"/>
<bean id="mysiteProductModelUrlResolver"
      class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.url.impl.DefaultProductModelUrlResolver">
    <property name="threadContextService" ref="threadContextService"/>
    <property name="commerceCategoryService" ref="commerceCategoryService"/>
    <property name="baseSiteService" ref="baseSiteService"/>
    <property name="defaultPattern" value="/product/{product-code}"/>
    <property name="productAndCategoryHelper" ref="productAndCategoryHelper"/>
</bean>
```

and change `ProductPageController` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/**/product")`